# Enviar url activa mediante api de whatsapp

Tags: php, whatsapp

Tengo una pagina web en el cual tengo el catalogo de mis productos, lo que quiero es que me apoyen con el código en PHP de un botón que pueda obtener la url activa (del articulo que el visitante esta viendo) para incluirla con el código https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=... para que al momento de abrir conversación en *whatsapp* el operador sepa en que articulo esta interesado el visitante o en que pagina esta ubicado.

Gracias @JessHilario por la respuesta, yo no conozco de programación, lo poco que logro entender es lo que he leído y como tengo acceso a mi pagina web me he atrevido a realizar algunos cambios dentro de ella esta la de abrir una conversación por *whatsapp* por medio del siguiente codigo:

```
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=XXXXXXCX" target="_blank">
    <img src="http://misitio.com/app/webroot/img/DeepBlue/whats-coti.png">
</a>
```

Sin embargo he tratado de implementar el código que me proporciono pero no ha sido posible, lo he hecho sustituyéndolo así:

```
$actual_link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . ": //$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']";
$phone = "50257020363"; // Dejar vacio si quieres que el usuario elija a quien enviar el mensaje
$message = "Hola! Me intereso mucho este articulo y creo que a ti también puede llegar a interesarte";
$message = str_replace(" ", "%20", $message); // Remplazamos los espacios por su equivalente
$wa_link = "https://wa.me/$phone?text=$message%20$actual_link";
echo "<a href=\"$wa_link\"">Compartir este articulo en WhatsApp</a>;
```

¿Podrían apoyarme con el código completo para el botón o link que me lleve a *whatsapp*? o ¿indicarme como podría hacerlo? en que parte debo indicarle el signo de apertura y cierre de php, etc.

No esta demás comentar que el archivo tiene extensión `.ctp` pero por lo que puedo ver la programación esta en php.

Gracias y disculpen la molestia.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes obtener la url actual mediante el siguiente código:

```
$actual_link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']";
```

- `$_SERVER['HTTPS']`: Permite saber si el servidor cuenta con HTTPS
- `$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]`: Obtiene el host del servidor (ej: google.com)
- `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`: Obtiene el uri actual (ej: /servicios)

Por su parte la API de WhatsApp acepta el parametro `text` el cual puedes usar para enviar la url junto con el texto que tu quieras. Por ejmplo:

```
$phone = ""; // Dejar vacio si quieres que el usuario elija a quien enviar el mensaje
$message = "Hola! Me intereso mucho este articulo y creo que a ti también puede llegar a interesarte";
$message = str_replace(" ", "%20", $message); // Remplazamos los espacios por su equivalente

$wa_link = "https://wa.me/$phone?text=$message%20$actual_link";

echo "<a href=\"$wa_link\"">Compartir este articulo en WhatsApp</a>;
```

Fuente: https://faq.whatsapp.com/es/android/26000030/

Saludos!

Comment: Podria apoyarme con el codigo completo para el boton o link que me lleve a whatsapp? o indicarme como podria hacerlo? en que parte debo indicarle el signo de apertura y cierre de php, etc.

no esta de mas comentar que el archivo tiene extension .ctp pero por lo que puedo ver la programacion esta en php.

gracias y disculpe la molestia.